# useState getting confused when using multiple components

Tags: react-native, react-hooks

The action taken to update the state in a functional component is incorrectly updating the state of the final component loaded.

I have simplified what I'm doing to very simple code. I'm wondering if I'm missing something in why this does not work

This is parent component that loops to create subcomponents.

```
         {scoreDays.length >0 ? scoreDays.map((el,idx) =>(
          <ScoringDay key={idx} date ={el.day} score={el.score} 
            channels={el.channels} />
            )) : null}
```

This is the ScoringDay component. I'm simply using a button press to update the text in state and have it displayed.

```
         const ScoringDay = props => {
        [expanded, setExpanded] = useState(false);
        [test, setTest] = useState('starting text');

       return(
    <View>
    <Text>
        {test}
        </Text>
        <Text onPress={() =>setTest('Clicked here')}>Update value</Text>
    </View>
        )
```

In my example, 3 "ScoringDay" components are shown on the screen. However, no matter which text "Update value" I click, it always updates the text on the last component.

Why isn't the action being applied to the correct component?? I am using an index on the key...but not sure what else needs to be changed here?

[image]

Comment: It looks like you might be having an issue with the keys. You seem to be using the `.map` index as the key which should be fine if the array elements are always in the same position; is this the case? Could you try setting a unique id to each and using it for the `key`?

Answer (score 0):

Run the status change from parent to child.

```js
      [testtext, setTestText] = useState('starting text');
...
        {scoreDays.length >0 ? scoreDays.map((el,idx) =>(
          <ScoringDay key={idx} date ={el.day} score={el.score} 
            channels={el.channels} testtext={testtext} setTestText={setTestText} />
            )) : null}
```

**Used**

```js
         const ScoringDay = props => {
        [expanded, setExpanded] = useState(false);
        const { testtext, setTestText} = props
       return(
    <View>
    <Text>
        {testtext}
        </Text>
        <Text onPress={() =>setTestText('Clicked here')}>Update value</Text>
    </View>
        )
```